# Spree offsite payments Payu.in integration: how to mark an order as paid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am new to ruby/rails/spree. I am implementing Indian payment gateway with `spree-3.0.7`.
I am able to process the order but payment status is always at `balance_due`.
Controller code

```
def confirm
  payment_method = Spree::PaymentMethod.find(payment_method_id)

  Spree::LogEntry.create({
    source: payment_method,
    details: params.to_yaml
  })

  order = current_order || raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)

  if(address = order.bill_address || order.ship_address)
    firstname = address.firstname
  end

  #confirm for correct hash and order amount requested before marking an payment as 'complete'
  checksum_matched = payment_method.checksum_ok?([params[:status], '', '', '', '', '', '', params[:udf4], params[:udf3], params[:udf2], params[:udf1], order.email, firstname, @productinfo, params[:amount], params[:txnid]], params[:hash])
  if !checksum_matched
    flash.alert = 'Malicious transaction detected.'
    redirect_to checkout_state_path(order.state)
    return
  end
  #check for order amount
  if !payment_method.amount_ok?(order.total, params[:amount])
    flash.alert = 'Malicious transaction detected. Order amount not matched.'
    redirect_to checkout_state_path(order.state)
    return
  end

  payment = order.payments.create!({
    source_type: 'Spree::Gateway::Payumoney',#could be something generated by system
    amount: order.total,
    payment_method: payment_method
  })
  payment.started_processing!
  payment.pend!

  order.next
  order.update_attributes({:state => "complete", :completed_at => Time.now})

  if order.complete?
    order.update!
    flash.notice = Spree.t(:order_processed_successfully)

    redirect_to order_path(order)
    return
  else
    redirect_to checkout_state_path(order.state)
    return
  end
end
```

Gateway/Model Code

```
require "offsite_payments"
module Spree
  class Gateway::Payumoney < Gateway
    preference :merchant_id, :string
    preference :secret_key, :string


  def provider_class
    ::OffsitePayments.integration('Payu_In')
  end

  def provider
    #assign payment mode
    OffsitePayments.mode = preferred_test_mode == true ? :test : :production
    provider_class
  end

  def checksum(items)
    provider_class.checksum(preferred_merchant_id, preferred_secret_key, items)
  end    

  def auto_capture?
    true
  end

  def method_type
    "payumoney"
  end

  def support?(source)
    true
  end

  def authorization
    self
  end

  def purchase(amount, source, gateway_options={})
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response.new(true, "payumoney success")
  end

  def success?
    true
  end

  def txnid(order)
    order.id.to_s + order.number.to_s
  end

  def service_provider
    "payu_paisa"
  end

  def checksum_ok?(itms, pg_hash)
    Digest::SHA512.hexdigest([preferred_secret_key, *itms, preferred_merchant_id].join("|")) == pg_hash
  end

  def amount_ok?(order_total, pg_amount)
    BigDecimal.new(pg_amount) == order_total
  end
end
```

in spree payment doc https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/payments.html they have mentioned if `auto_capture?` return `true` then purchase method will be called but purchase method is not getting called.
Can anyone point me to right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by marking payment as complete.

remove

```
payment.started_processing!
payment.pend!
```

add

```
payment.complete
```

above

```
order.next
```

I have published my code at github as gem
https://github.com/isantoshsingh/spree_payumoney

Comment: Please refer this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666949/spree-offsite-payments-payu-in-integration-how-to-mark-an-order-as-paid/35739951?noredirect=1#comment59155688_35739951) once.

Answer (score 1):

You **need not call** the following commands

`payment.started_processing!
payment.pend!`

Just leave the payment in its initial state. i.e. `checkout` state and complete your order.

Because when order is completed `process_payments!` is called.
This method processes unprocessed payments whose criteria is like below

`def unprocessed_payments
  payments.select { |payment| payment.checkout? }
end`

Hope this solves your case :)

Comment: but `purchase` method is not getting called. I have several failed attempt with and without those 2 commands.

Comment: may be that is because you have used `update_attributes` to mark order `complete` and not by using the `state_machine`.
try `while order.next; end` instead of `order.update_attributes({:state => "complete", :completed_at => Time.now})`

if you check `checkout.rb` there are callbacks in `state_machine` for payment_processing when order transits to `complete` state.

Comment: I have tried `while order.next; end` but this not even marking the order as complete.

Comment: Did you look for any errors on order object? Since, if there are errors, next would not transit the order further.
Just put a `debugger` before `order.next` and see whats the last state it transits to. And if any errors shown.

Comment: No I didn't see any error. `spree_orders` table has `state` as `payment` and `spree_payments` table has `state` as `checkout`. no error message at all.

Comment: No brother, add a `debugger` and check `order.errors` after making each transition with `order.next`